# How can I call a Simulink function that is located 2 levels above the Function Caller block?

Tags: matlab, function, simulink, function-call

I have a function caller block two levels beneath a Simulink function. If I call the function with just one level apart, the model will simulate flawlessly. With two levels apart, Simulink will return the Error: [Provide Input argument specifications and Output argument specifications for the Function Caller block 'X/X_Z_s/SDA_SDB' because the corresponding Simulink function could not be resolved to within this hierarchy, model, or any referenced model.]
I can't place function and function caller somewhere else.

Does somebody know how to solve this problem? I've been working on it for two days now.

Comment: Welcome to SO!... Can you please put the actual line from the parameter which function to call in your question?

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I'm not allowed to give you the *actual* line so I have encoded it. I hope you are still able to help me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not specifically with the hierarchy, but also with the "Input" and "Output argument specification". You have to give the interfacing datatypes and dimensions here.

**EXAMPLE**

[image]

Comment: OK, that did something. Now I'm getting the Error:
[The scoped function '...' called by block '...' has not been defined in the model. Calls to scoped functions must be resolved within a model. Ensure that the scope name (Subsystem block or Referenced Model block) does not have whitespaces.]

Comment: @trisp3ar What do you have as "Function prototype"?

Comment: The function prototype equals the excact function as discriped in the called Simulink Function-block.

Comment: @trisp3ar What version of MATLAB are you using?

Comment: I'm using R2019a (9.6.0.1072779)
I was just told that this function might not work since the block was generated with the AUTOSAR toolbox. AUTOSAR may have restricted the use of it. Do you have any information on this?

Comment: Sadly not. I set up a simple example to test it and it works just fine. I do not have the AUTOSAR Toolbox and have neither experience.

Comment: You are right, I have tried it without AUTOSAR and runs flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution is very simple. There is no solution.
The AUTOSAR-Toolbox restricts the use of certain Matlab/Simulink functions, thus making it very dificult to solve problems with the help of The Matlab/Simulink-, SO-community and other forums.
If you have a problem/error caused by the AUTOSAR-Toolbox, that would normally work without any toolboxes, you are best off just working around it even if it's inefficient.